# Extract all single characters from sentence in one match

Tags: regex, watson-assistant

I need to use regular expressions to draw all the individual letters from the entire sentence, and the result must be in only one group, it can not be a separate group.
E.g:

This is an example sentence in which I have two letters:

```
a and b
```

Score:

Match: ab

Below is my regex, and one most important thing, befor i can't use regex with: `"(?<!"`

```
\b[A-Za-z]\b
```

So far I have:

```
Match1: a
Match2: b
```

Comment: It seems OK to have non-language specific regex questions, although it doesn't hurt to tag the flavor (whatever it is, negative lookbehinds are unsupported). The larger problem is that it's unclear what's being asked here. Can OP clarify?

Comment: To get desired result, why not simply join all your matches ?

Comment: i want use this reges in IBM Watson Assistant. This service use basic regular expression. When i use For example this: ` (?<![\w\-])\w(?![\w\-]) then Watson return me some notification, that (?<! is wrong syntax

Comment: How can i join all matches by regex?

Comment: You can't. But if it's possible to perform a search and replace with regex there's a way.

Comment: Can you explain how?

Comment: A replacement with an empty string: https://regex101.com/r/hTkaSe/1

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I would recommend.

1. Match just the stand alone word chars in a global match.
   This will get them into a list.

`(?<!\w)\w(?!\w)`

https://regex101.com/r/uKNMg1/1

2. Use the split function with this regex which is the inverse of the one above.
   This removes all the multiple word chars and puts the letters into a list.

`(?s)(?:(?!(?<!\w)\w(?!\w)).)+`

https://regex101.com/r/pJtRdp/1